# How Do I Get a Reference to a Text Box Control Instead of the Text Box's Value in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

This seems so simple, but I can't figure out how to get a reference to a Text Box control in the Details section of a form instead of the Text Box's value in VBA.

Here's my exact code.  I'm wrapping the DoCmd.FindRecord method to support searching in a specified field on a form or anywhere on the form.  To search only in a specified field, I pass the control name.

```
Public Function FindExactRecord(frm As Form, strField As String, strFind As String) As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ERR_FUNC
    
    Dim rc As Boolean
    Dim ctrl As control
    
    rc = True                   ' Presume true
    
    If strField = "" Then
        ' Find the record anywhere on the form
        Call DoCmd.FindRecord(strFind, acEntire, True, acSearchAll, False, acAll, True)
    Else
        ' NOTE:  Currently not working!
        ' Set the current field
        Set ctrl = frm.Controls(strField)
        frm.ctrl.SetFocus
        
        ' Find the record in the specified field
        Call DoCmd.FindRecord(strFind, acEntire, True, acSearchAll, False, acCurrent, True)
        
        ' Check if record found
        rc = (frm.ctrl = strFind)
    End If
  
    ' Return success or failure
    FindExactRecord = rc
End Function
```

You'd think that would set ctrl to a reference to the txtBox control, but it actually sets ctrl to a string containing the value contained in txtBox (because Me.txtBox actually is an implicit reference to the default property of the txtBox, which is Value).  This causes the call to frm.ctrl.SetFocus call to throw error #2465 (Application-defined or object-defined error).  If I pass in the empty string for the control name (and therefore search the entire form), I don't get the error (because I don't reference the control at all).

I've tried various other ways to avoid getting the default property, but none of them work.

What's the magic to get a reference to the control?

Comment: http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/primer/

Comment: Thanks, but I had already read that before posting.  Is there a specific part you're referring to?

Comment: Set works for me. Of course default property of ctrl will be Value if it is a data control. If you don't want Value then specify property you do want. Show code that is real issue. What do you want to do with ctrl?

Comment: Ctrl is NOT set to a string, it is Set to textbox control object. Ctrl is an object with properties, including Value if it is a data control. So when you reference Ctrl without specifying a property it uses default. Why do you think you need this object variable?

Comment: I've edited my initial post to show the exact code.  I'm trying to reference a Text Box in the Details section of the form.  The Text Box is Locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As June7 wrote, you are misinterpreting something (you didn't show what).

`ctrl` is indeed a reference to the textbox control.
Try this:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

Set ctrl = Me.txtBox

' These wouldn't work, if ctrl was simply the string in txtBox
Debug.Print ctrl.Name
Debug.Print ctrl.BackColor
' These will both print the content
Debug.Print ctrl
Debug.Print ctrl.Value
```

---

```
frm.ctrl.SetFocus
```

This looks for a property `ctrl` in the form object (and fails).

Simply use `ctrl.SetFocus`, and replace `frm.ctrl` by `ctrl` anywhere else too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
        ' Set the current field
        Set ctrl = frm.Controls(strField)
        ctrl.SetFocus
        
        ' Make sure, that frm is the selected and active form.
        ' Find the record in the specified field
        Call DoCmd.FindRecord(strFind, acEntire, True, acSearchAll, False, acCurrent, True)
        
        ' Check if record found
        rc = (ctrl.Value = strFind)
```

Comment: DOH!  Where's my dunce cap.  :-X  Thanks, and I marked your reply as the answer.